# Indentation problem in lists using custom label

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

I am having a small problem using lists with a custom label for each item. When I use the following code, the list item is not indented correctly, it uses the second number after the `\Rightarrow` to indent the paragraph

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent Some text before
\begin{enumerate}
\item[$(1)\Rightarrow (2)$:] Proof 1 
\item[$(2)\Leftrightarrow (3)$:] Proof 2
\item[$(2)\Rightarrow (1)$:] Proof 3
\end{enumerate}
Some text after
\end{document}
```

I tried using the `\indent` command as well as `\hspace`, but I can't get it to work. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: In my opinion a simple paragraph headed with `$(1)\Rightarrow(2)$:` suffices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should force the adjustment to be `left` using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent Some text before
\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
  \item[$(1)\Rightarrow (2)$:] Proof 1 
  \item[$(2)\Leftrightarrow (3)$:] Proof 2
  \item[$(2)\Rightarrow (1)$:] Proof 3
\end{enumerate}
Some text after
\end{document}
```

A global setting is also possible via `\setlist[enumerate]{align=left}`.

Comment: This looks better. Would it be possible to make them indent like a proper list?

Comment: @user2287089: You can play around with the `leftmargin=<len>` key where you specify some LaTeX length `<len>` (like 3em).

Comment: Thanks, I used `leftmargin=3.5em` and it worked perfectly!